# jquery colorbox title attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, colorbox, title

How could the region available to display the title be expanded to handle a long, multiline, more descriptive title string? Only the height would need to be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do that through JavaScript. Have a look at this jQuery plugin [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/)